# why append the element to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying make a form with jquery/ajax

Here what I am doing:

```
    var form="<form id='frm'>name: <input type='text' id='name' name='name' /> <br />";
    $("#productos").append(form);

    $.get("bb.php").done(function (data){
          $("#frm").append(data); // this return a select
    });

    $("#frm").append("<p id='a1'>aa</p>");
    $("#productos").append("</form>");
```

I was expecting this:

```
<form id="frm">
    name: <input id="nombre" type="text" name="name"></input>
    <select> … </select>
    <p id="a1"> … </p>
</form>
```

But this is what I get:

```
    <form id="frm">
        name: <input id="nombre" type="text" name="name"></input>
        <p id="a1"> … </p>
        <select> … </select>        
    </form>
```

I know I could use insertbefore, but I would like to know why this happens, and if there is another way to fix

Comment: `... .append('</form>');` -- this is not the way how elements can be inserted in the DOM. Moreover, ajax request is asynchronous, hence appending of your `<select>` element will be done only when the request is successfully completed.

Comment: @VisioN thanks. I realized that isn't the correct way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your callback, which you are specifying here -

```
$.get("bb.php").done(function (data){
      $("#frm").append(data); // this return a select
});
```

executes after you get a response from the server, while -

```
$("#frm").append("<p id='a1'>aa</p>");
```

this line executes immediately after your ajax request fires, before you receive a response. As a result, your paragraph is appearing before your `select`.

If you want to maintain the order, then do it like this -

```
$.get("bb.php").done(function (data){
    $("#frm").append(data); // this return a select
    $("#frm").append("<p id='a1'>aa</p>"); // now append the paragraph
});
```

or -

```
$.get("bb.php").done(function (data){
    $(data).insertBefore('#a1'); // this return a select
});

$("#frm").append("<p id='a1'>aa</p>");
```

Comment: Both work, thank you. Which is the most common or better way to use ?

Comment: @Don: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want your paragraph to be available in the DOM before the response comes, use the second one. Otherwise use the first one.